# NULL character found in serialized string

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

I am unable to `unserialize()` a backtrace that I `serialize()`'d and saved to a text file. I cannot also copy-paste the string, it only copies the data before NULL so I am unable to unserialize it back in PHP.

Here's a small excerpt of what it looks like in Notepad++

[image]

Any ideas how to unserialize this?

Note: I am using `error_log($backtrace, 3, 'file.log');` to save the file, then simply open in Notepad++ to copy-paste but I can't copy past the NULL character.

Comment: Might be due to utf-8 and ascii conflict. Make sure both the file and the system uses the same enconding.

Comment: Would `preg_replace()` work? (I may have misunderstood the question)

Comment: Did you copy-paste the serialized data into a text editor in order to save it or did you use something like `fwrite()` from PHP?

Comment: @Narf I used PHP's error_log function (edited my post)

Comment: @IMB I don't think that `error_log()` is binary safe - that would be the most logical explanation.

Comment: @Narf What would be a better way to save in text files?

Comment: @IMB For serialized data - by either `fwrite()` or `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: @Narf That seems to work when I open the log file in plain Notepad (not Notepad++)

Comment: Yeah, the plain Notepad will always show raw data. :)

Answer (score 3):

So the serialize function identifies member variables with the syntax null*null as you are showing here.

The null character is encoded in a string as `\0` and is not usually displayed in output. To unserialize you will need to convert those "null" text back to `\0`.

When I write a serialized array I run it through a function that converts `\0` to `[NULL]`.

```
$string = str_replace("\0","[NULL]",$string);
```

Then when you're ready to unserialize you can just do the opposite

```
$string = str_replace("[NULL]","\0",$string);
```

Comment: Just make object properties public.